# Deep Linking in iOS - Navigate to Apple Store if app not installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, deep-linking

I need to implement `Deep Linking` concept without using any third party libraries (Branch and etc..). The link (starts with http/https) will be shared from app through Message, Email or any Social media apps. By tapping on shared link I want to open corresponding app if its already installed on device else it should navigate to the Apple Store to download the app.

I have knowledge on URL schemas but it works only when the app is already installed on device and the schema URL format also be different (like fb:// for Facebook app).

I have also done some R&D on `Universal Links` but I don't know whether it supports for dynamic links as for me the link will be combination of base URL(static) and referrer key(dynamic). I also need to track the referrer information once the corresponding app is opened like who referred this app (referrer details). 
e.g: https://domain.com/ReferrerID
Can you please help me on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the requirement to avoid third-party libraries?

Comment: Third parties are not free.

Comment: Hmm...no, actually they are. Both Firebase Dynamic Links and [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) are completely free for everything you've described.

Comment: @AlexBauer, Branch is charging $ 0.02 for each click right?

Comment: Only for certain more advanced features. The basic infrastructure used by 99% of Branch apps (including Pinterest, Airbnb, Tinder, etc.) is — and will always be — free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it clear on `Universal Links` in `iOS` will not take you to Apple Store if app is not installed on device. When you click on a link then `Universal Links` helps you to open the app if the app is already installed on device else the same link will be going to browse in `Safari`. When the url browse in Safari then we have to run `JavaScript` to navigate/redirect to Apple Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can support universal links to your application from iOS 9 or above. You can generate dynamic links and have deferred deep linking also.
Follow this steps its simple [Click Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

For the file mentioned in the link you need to add that file in the root of your website which consists of the path valid for deeplinking. And that file should not have any extension.

Then validate your domain at [Here](http://search.developer.apple.com).

After that you can add all the domains thing in your associated domain under the project capabilites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have looked into Apple website before posting the question. In website they said that "Create an apple-app-site-association file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle." which means we have to keep URLs in a file. So how can we add links dynamically to file? please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Universal links works when the app is installed on device else it will open link in Safari. But how can I navigate to Apple Store if the app is not installed on device?

Comment: @GaneshGuturi It will navigate to the AppStore if you have correct identifier and prefix set in apple-app-site file...

Comment: @ Parth Adroja, They have not mentioned that it will navigate to Apple Store if your app is not installed. I checked their document and they mentioned "When you support universal links, iOS 9 users can tap a link to your website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without going through Safari. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to your website opens your website in Safari." . Have you done this before?

Comment: What BranchIO there is option for that for the redirection. But if you do it manually then you might have to redirect to App Store. I guess it should work without doing that.

Comment: @GaneshG I want to do the implementation similar to the one u asked without using any third party. Have u found any solution then please do share? Really stuck with this :(